# Missing Frameworks/Xcode Upgrade?

Tags: xcode

So I'm getting problems when trying to make in iPhone app in Xcode (version 3.1.4)... I'm trying to use the ExternalAccessory Framework but it didn't exist in my System/Library ... /Frameworks directory. Is there any way to get it or a place to download it? I tried to upgrade to Xcode 4 but I was unsure of how to transfer my old projects to there and after much frustration ended up just staying with the only version, perhaps I should try again?

Comment: After installing Xcode the ExternalAccessory framework should be located at: `/System/Library/Frameworks/ExternalAccessory.framework`

Comment: Yeah... problem is that it isn't, maybe a reinstallation? or is there a place where I can download that framework directly?

Comment: Like Sean I too am missing ExternalAccessory.framework from /System/Library/Frameworks.  I have searched the entire drive to no avail.  I have XCode 4.3.3 installed.  All sources suggest that the framework should be there so offer no solution if it is not.  How do I locate this framework so I can proceed with my project?

Answer (score 0):

Having run into the same problem with XCode 4.3.3 I bit the bullet and installed XCode 4.5.  Fortunately my project wasn't broken by the upgrade (as has been the case in the past) and the ExternalAccessory library is now available.

Answer (score 0):

In the project navigator, select your project
Select your target
Select the 'Build Phases' tab
Open 'Link Binaries With Libraries' expander
Click the '+' button
Select your framework